# Globally configure search dropdown

Tags: 2013, search, result-source

- I have created a custom result source "special results" at CA-level
- A search result page is created in the search center, searching only "special results"
- The dropdown in the search center displays "special results, Everything, Conversations..."

I connected the global search center to some other random site. This site only displays "Everything, Conversations, ..." and "special results" is missing. This blog post suggests that I am out of luck: [SharePoint 2013 Search Settings and Search drop down menu](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-search-settings-and-search-box-drop-down-menu).

Is the solution really that I have to adjust each and every sub-site's settings of the search dropdown and recreate the default links to the respective result sources (Video, Everything) and add my own link to my "special" result source? Also: When doing so the "search this site" result source is missing - am I supposed to add a manual link to ossearchresults.aspx?

How could I script this if I really have to do this for every web? Where to the navigation nodes reside?

---

Once more in short:
I want my search dropdown look like so:

- Special Results
- Everything
- Conversations
- Videos

I want to define the dropdown once (in the search center) and I want all other sites to inherit from that. It seems that this is not possible and I would have to recreate the search dropdown for each and every site.

Comment: What does "I connected the global search center to some other random site" mean?

Comment: Site > Site Settings > Search Settings > Search Center URL means "connected" to me